# Nuget Packages Restore Problem After Cloning Project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, remote-desktop, .net-framework-version

I'm having a problem which occured when I cloned a .Net Framework project to a Remote Desktop Machine. I have cloned the project and starting to build it. I'm using Visual Studio 22 and the project is on .Net Framework 4.6.2, so VS have auto restore for the NuGet packages, but still I'm getting this error. I don't know what is the problem and how to solve it. I tried everything that is on Stackoverflow without success.. I don't know from where is comming this problem and what is causing it.. Thanks in advance for the help!

[image: Console Error]

This is the list of the things that I have tried to resolve this issue but none of them is working:

1: Deleted .vs, bin, obj, packages folders from the project.

2: Upgrade the .Net Version and downgrade to the 4.6.2 just to see if something is going to change.

3: Installed VS 2019 in case any dll's are missing because the project framework is old.

4: Tried `Update-Package -Reinstall`

5: I'm Admin and I have full permissions on the RDM.

6: Tried to set a local nuget folder so the packages can be getted locally, but it doesn't worked, i'm seeing the same error.

7: Reinstall VS

8: Copied the packages from my local machine to the virtual, but then all references are not found, even System's.

9: Removed the target from the csproj file. The project is building but the packages folder is still empty, so the nuget packages are not downloaded.

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Grpc.Core.2.46.6\build\net45\Grpc.Core.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Grpc.Core.2.46.6\build\net45\Grpc.Core.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.2022.10.9530\build\net452\IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.2022.10.9530\build\net452\IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

My expectations was to build the project, directly after cloning it and run in on the virtual machine, from where are this problems coming with the references and nuget packages?

Comment: can you give more details which package is missing? Maybe it is an private package, which is not distributed via standard repositories? You can see the package in visual studio in your project under references. There should be an exclamation mark indicating problematic packages.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens The missing file is ..\packages\Grpc.Core.2.46.6\build\net45\Grpc.Core.target. The strange thing is that If I remove the <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"> from the csproj file, the project is building but the folder with the packages is still empty.

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, but what about right-click your project ín solution explorer and "restore NuGet packages"? Am I thinking too simple?

Comment: @Mahobo this is not working, that was the first thing that I tried and also from VS 2019 I think, when you open a solution, restore NuGet packages is executing automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, the only solution that worked for me was to copy the existing packages from NuGet on my local PC and to copy them to the virtual machine, but this is some workaround that I figure out.